# Is my question about the machine code syntax of a CISC instruction set binary on-topic?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Edit: I now understand there are specific CISC standards for different CPUs, I'm currently trying to understand that concept better so I can properly specify / narrow the question. I guess pause this discussion until I fix that.

Sometimes it's hard to know the right question to ask even if you do your research on a topic. You don't know what you don't know.

---

I asked: [What is the machine code syntax of a CISC instruction set binary?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64354919/what-is-the-machine-code-syntax-of-a-cisc-instruction-set-binary)

I'm conflicted about whether my question is acceptable or not. In a sense, if we consider machine code a programming language, then my question is essentially asking about the formatting syntax of an entire language, which sounds extremely broad. But on the other hand, that programming language's syntax structure consists of about 6 components, making it essentially the simplest (albeit hardest to read) language in the world.

I think that fact that the ideal answer would be a 6 component ACII chart with explanations theoretically meets the fourth bullet in the sense of being a "practical, answerable" problem unique to software development.

- a specific programming problem, or
- a software algorithm, or
- software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
- **a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development**

But it's definitely questionable. Is there somewhere better on SE I could be asking?

Comment: ".. the formatting syntax of an entire language .." – but you do not specify for *what* "language", i.e., a specific CPU.

Comment: @usr2564301 I'll admit I'm confused about that because I can compile a single EXE and send it to 30 different PCs, each with a different processor and (modern, 7, 8, 10) version of Windows and I think it runs on most or all of them (assuming I'm not calling an incompatible OS feature). What's the standard of CISC called that modern (7+) Windows uses? Is x86 the name of a standard?

Comment: Not really on topic, but all of the processors would have implemented the x86-64 instruction set https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86-64

Answer (score 2):

So researching this, my question seems to have been misguided.

It sounds like all compiled programs sort of actually behave like interpreted languages in a fundamental sense, as the binary of compiled executables we commonly interact with is not raw CISC machine code ready to be fed to the processor, but rather assembly code ready to be converted (compiled? interpreted?) into a CISC architecture based on that processor. So my question was fundamentally flawed.

You don't know what you don't know. I guess even asking a bad/misguided question can be a learning experience on SO.

Comment: This is slightly off-topic for meta, but you probably need to look at the concept of specific instruction set architectures (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instruction_set_architecture) and are getting confused by microcode. In any compiled program, the program will be converted to binary instructions which target a specifc instruction set architecture. A number of different processors may be able to execute that architecture, (for example all intel core and AMD Ryzen processors execute x86-64).

Comment: Assembly code usually refers to the textual representation of those instructions used by humans, whereas machine code is used to refer to the binary representation used by the actual processors.
Then finally there is microcode, which is used in some (but not all) processors to translate from the complex general instructions to simpler internal instructions, and is usually specific to a single generation of processor by a specific manufacturer.

Comment: `as the binary of compiled executables we commonly interact with is not raw CISC machine code ready to be fed to the processor, but rather assembly code ...` -- Well, sort of.  Compilers can emit all sorts of output, from source code in another language to byte code instructions that must be fed into a JIT interpreter for execution.  And yes, they can also emit raw machine instructions.  Just depends on what your needs are.

Comment: And to add to levels of "compiler output" listed in @RobertHarvey comment (other high level language, other lower level language, byte code, CPU byte code) - there are also compilers that output even at level lower - [https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcode]...

Answer (score 0):

The core of the question seem to be "To do that, I need a diagram (or even an ACII chart) depicting the breakdown and format of how each instruction is represented in binary" which is asking for off-site resource and hence off-topic on the site.

Indeed there are other issues with the question

- it seem to use CISC as some very specific CPU (possibly "can run regular Windows on / X64") which is very unusual interpretation (check out [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_instruction_set_computer)). This may attract "need more details" close votes to narrow down the question
- it also feels more of a discussion/teaching session type of question rather than asking for something specific. While it is not explicitly off-topic it may be perceived as overly broad and also closed as such. I would expect a question about singe/group of instructions for particular CPU would be considered on-topic by most users while questions with broader scope are likely start attracting "too broad" votes.
- and for the specific topic CISC vs. RISC is somewhat opinion based as pretty much any classification. Modern CPUs are essentially mix of two approaches and (while a stretch) this question could be seen as invitation to discuss whether a given CPU is CISC/RISC or not.